# Factoring a scalar function out of a vector

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've taken a first and second derivative:

```
In[11]:= f = Exp[-2*t]*{Cos[3*t], Sin[3*t], 1}

Out[11]= {E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t], E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t], E^(-2 t)}

In[12]:= D[f, t]

Out[12]= {-2 E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t] - 3 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t], 
 3 E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t] - 2 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t], -2 E^(-2 t)}

In[13]:= D[f, {t, 2}]

Out[13]= {-5 E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t] + 
  12 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t], -12 E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t] - 5 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t], 
 4 E^(-2 t)}
```

Now I am wondering how I can factor out E^(-2 t), showing the final answer in the form:

$$e^{-2t}[-5\cos3t+12\sin3t,-12\cos 3t-5\sin 3t,4]$$

Answer (score 6):

One way to achieve this is:

```
expr = {-5 E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t] + 12 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t], -12 E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t] - 5 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t], 
        4 E^(-2 t)}
```

Then:

```
Collect[expr, E^(-2 t)] /. {x_ u_, x_ v_, x_ w_} :> x[u, v, w]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Harry's approach

```
v = {-5 E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t] + 12 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t], -12 E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t] - 
    5 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t], 4 E^(-2 t)};

factor = Intersection @@ (Factor /@ v);

expr = Inactive[Times][factor, Simplify[v/factor]]
```

[image]

```
v == (expr // Activate) // Simplify
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

maybe we can use Intersection to find the factor:

```
v = {-5 E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t] + 
12 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t], -12 E^(-2 t) Cos[3 t] - 5 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t],
4 E^(-2 t)};
factor = Intersection @@ (Factor /@ v);
factor[Simplify[v/factor]]
(*(E^(-2 t))[{-5 Cos[3 t] + 12 Sin[3 t], -12 Cos[3 t] - 5 Sin[3 t], 4}]*)
```

I have to say the output is a little bit ugly. Maybe there is a better way to prevent the factor timed into the list again.